# Set duplicated value in a column with different colors for each set values but ignore non-duplicates

Tags: google-apps-script

In a sheet with duplicates sorted to the Top.

I need to alternate the background color for each set of duplicates but ignore the non-duplicate cells.

For duplicates in column `A` I have the following function, but it colors the non-duplicates as well.

How to Keep the function from giving the non-duplicate cells a background color

Have

[image]

Want

[image]

```
function conditionalColors() {
  const sS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  /* Filter the values to obtain true when the time changes */
  const values = sS
    .getRange('A2:A')
    .getValues()
    .filter(n => n[0] !== '')
    .flat()
    .map((n, idx, crrArr) => idx === 0 ? true : crrArr[idx-1] !== crrArr[idx])

    console.log(values) //

  /* defining the colors*/
  const color1 = [204, 222, 188]
  const color2 = [238, 232, 170]
  let color = color1

  /* Loop to change the color every time we have a true */
  values.forEach((c, idx) => {
    if (c) {
         console.log(c) //
      color = color === color1 ? color2 : color1
    }

    sS.getRange(idx + 2, 1).setBackgroundRGB(...color)
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it can be done with this separate function:

```
function remove_colors() {
  const sS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const range = sS.getRange('A2:A' + sS.getLastRow());
  const values = range.getValues().flat();
  const colors = range.getBackgroundColors();

  for (var i in values)
    if (values.indexOf(values[i]) == values.lastIndexOf(values[i]))
      colors[i] = [undefined];

  range.setBackgrounds(colors)
}
```

But this code will work faster:

```
function conditionalColors() {
  const sS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  const range = sS.getRange('A2:A' + sS.getLastRow());
  const values = range.getValues().flat();
  const colors = values.map(x => [null]);

  const rgb_hex = (r,g,b) =>
    '#' + [r,g,b].map(x => x.toString(16).padStart(2,0)).join``;

  const c1 = rgb_hex(204, 222, 188);
  const c2 = rgb_hex(238, 232, 170);
  let toggle = false;

  for (let i in values) {
    if (values.indexOf(values[i]) == values.lastIndexOf(values[i])) break;
    if (i > 1 && values[i-1] != values[i]) toggle = !toggle;
    colors[i] = (toggle) ? [c1] : [c2]
  }

  range.setBackgrounds(colors); // recolor all the range at once
}
```

It uses less number of calls to the server.